# Trying to delete ":view: in Telescope. Is something wrong with my code?

Tags: meteor, telescope

I want to get rid of the "view:" text from the template in Telescope.

This is my client/lib/config.js file:

```
module.exports = {



     banner: '/**\n' +
              ' * core-js ' + require('../package').version + '\n' +
              ' * https://github.com/zloirock/core-js\n' +
              ' * License: http://rock.mit-license.org\n' +
              ' * © ' + new Date().getFullYear() + ' Denis Pushkarev\n' +
              ' */'
              Telescope.modules.remove("top","posts_views_nav");
            };
```

I've added **Telescope.modules.remove("top","posts_views_nav");**. However this does not seem to be working.

Could someone help?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure where you added that line.
I usually use my-custom-package to edit Telescope. Telescope overwrites original files with custom_ prefix files.

1. Create **custom_**modules.js
2. Make the changes you need.
3. Add custom_modules.js to package.js in your custom package folder.

Let me know it that helped.